# Angular get event on modal creation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Simple question,

I'm using Angular UI to show modals.

I have an application that opens multiple modals,

the modals has issue with the screen height and i added a code that optimize the modal size to the height of the screen.

The thing is i want to be notified when there is a new modal created so i can call my function for fixing the modal size.

Any ideas how i get notified for modal creation?

Thanks,

Examples of modal cration:

```
// create the modal instance and show the popup
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'partials\mymodal.html',
    windowClass: "modal fade in app-modal-window",
    controller: controllertest,
    resolve:{
        resultData:function(){ return null;}
    },
    backdrop: 'static',

    dialogFade: true,
    keyboard: false,
    fade:true,
    size:'lg'
});

// destroy the modal instance on cancel
var unbind_modal_popup = $scope.$on('$destroy', function ()
{
    if (modalInstance != undefined)
    {
        modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }
});

// return handler.
modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {


    // set the country field
    unbind_modal_popup();
}, function () {
    unbind_modal_popup();
})
};
```

Example of Modal HTML:

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope in small-modal" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="" window-class="modal fade in small-modal" size="sm" index="0" animate="animate">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" ng-class="{'modal-sm': size == 'sm', 'modal-lg': size == 'lg'}"><div class="modal-content" modal-transclude=""><div id="parameter-modal" class="ng-scope">
        <p>Text inside modal</p>
</div></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do have a scope property that holds a count of your modals, and watch that.

```
// set up a watcher:
$scope.$watch('modalCount', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal > oldVal) {
    // your login upon modal creation here
  }
});

// create the modal instance and show the popup
var modalInstance = function () {

  // call some service or change some scopeProperty that you watch e.g.
  $scope.modalCount++;
  // OR
  someService.modalCreated();

  return $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'partials\mymodal.html',
    windowClass: "modal fade in app-modal-window",
    controller: controllertest,
    resolve:{
        resultData:function(){ return null;}
    },
    backdrop: 'static',

    dialogFade: true,
    keyboard: false,
    fade:true,
    size:'lg'
  })();
};
```

You can also add that logic into the modal's controller, but then you need to add to an object property or just call some service (as in the second example).

Comment: The solution you suggested is not based on the modal creation process, but on the modalCount, i'm looking for a generic idea, by the  solution you did i need to make sure every modal in the code, and every future modal will hold this counter, i'm looking for something more sofisiticated.

Comment: Create a wrapper service that holds tge same function, and instead of accessing scope make it access that service's counters and methods. that way you can build on top of $modal. Just do the stuff in a custom service and not in the controller, and only call it from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The `$modal.open` method has a "opened" promise that gets resolved once the modal has been opened.

Something like this should work:

```
$modal.open().opened.then(function(){
  //Modal opened successfully.
});
```

Reference: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: is it global or should be added to each modal? i have 20 mondals in the code, i'm looking for something generic.

Comment: This particular promise will be for each modal creation. But I think you can decorate the $modal creation so that the logic of adding a "opened" handler stays in one location. I'll work on a sample implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i used css instead of code:

```
@media (max-height: 800px) {

  .modal {
    max-height:500px;
    overflow:auto;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 700px) {

  .modal {
    max-height:450px;
    overflow:auto;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 600px) {

  .modal {
    max-height:400px;
    overflow:auto;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 500px) {

  .modal {
    max-height:350px;
    overflow:auto;
  }
}
```